# SQLAlchemy: Avoid re-loading large objects from database after merge

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a `Blob` model to store large binary object in the (SQLite) database, addressable by their hash:

```py
class Blob(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blobs'
    hash = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(LargeBinary)

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.hash = _hash(data) #  a function to calculate hash from the data
        self.data = data
```

I would like to avoid savings the objects to the database if they are already there, essentially making `Blob.data` a content-addressable piece of information.

With a naive approach,

```py
b1 = Blob('This is a test')
session.add(b1)
session.commit()

b2 = Blob('This is a test')
session.add(b2)
session.commit()
```

I will get a `UNIQUE constrained failed` exception after the second `commit`, which is expected.

If I replace `add` with `merge` instead, I don't have this exception, as the second `commit` does nothing

```py
b1 = Blob('This is a test')
session.merge(b1)
session.commit()

b2 = Blob('This is a test')
session.merge(b2)
session.commit()
```

however I get an expensive `SELECT` after `session.merge(b2)`:

```
2020-11-01 22:03:51,579 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT blobs.hash AS blobs_hash, blobs.data AS blobs_data 
FROM blobs 
WHERE blobs.hash = ?
```

Here `blobs.data` is requested from the database, and I would like to avoid that as I know that `b2.data` is the same as `b1.data` (they have the same hash, `b1.hash == b2.hash`); imagine that `blobs.data` is a gigabyte-size object.

I tried to make `data` a deferred field:

```
data = column_property(Column(LargeBinary), deferred=True)
```

and with that, `session.merge(b2)` generate a small select:

```
2020-11-01 21:53:21,774 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT blobs.hash AS blobs_hash 
FROM blobs 
WHERE blobs.hash = ?
2020-11-01 21:53:21,774 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('qz78diGV8TjV31akJUBfHZUopUX5iC7rnHIUhQ==',)
```

however, the second commit generates an `UPDATE` to the database:

```
2020-11-01 21:53:21,775 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE blobs SET data=? WHERE blobs.hash = ?
2020-11-01 21:53:21,775 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (<memory at 0x10931b640>, 'qz78diGV8TjV31akJUBfHZUopUX5iC7rnHIUhQ==')
2020-11-01 21:53:21,775 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

which is sending unnecessary large data into the opposite direction.

What's the right strategy here to avoid sending large objects over the network that I know already exist in the database, and just update the state of the session object?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after spending a few hours poring over [Using the Session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session.html) section, here is the answer that seems to work:

1. Make `Blob.data` a deferred property:

```py
class Blob(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blobs'
    hash = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    data = column_property(Column(LargeBinary), deferred=True)

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.hash = _hash(data)
        self.data = data
```

2. Add a hook on `before_flush` event to remove all dirty `Blob` objects:

```py
@event.listens_for(Session, 'before_flush')
def ignore_dirty_blob_objects(session, flush_context, instances):
    for obj in session.dirty:
        if isinstance(obj, Blob):
            session.expunge(obj)
```

3. Always use `Session.merge` for adding objects to the session:

```py
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session.configure(bind=engine)

session = Session()

b1 = Blob('This is a test')
session.merge(b1)
session.commit()

b2 = Blob('This is a test')
session.merge(b2)
session.commit()
```

produces the following SQL statements. Notice that there is only one INSERT, and `blobs.data` is never selected from the DB:

```
2020-11-02 01:42:49,752 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT blobs.hash AS blobs_hash 
FROM blobs 
WHERE blobs.hash = ?
2020-11-02 01:42:49,752 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('qz78diGV8TjV31akJUBfHZUopUX5iC7rnHIUhQ==',)
2020-11-02 01:42:49,753 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO blobs (hash, data) VALUES (?, ?)
2020-11-02 01:42:49,753 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('qz78diGV8TjV31akJUBfHZUopUX5iC7rnHIUhQ==', <memory at 0x108a56400>)
2020-11-02 01:42:49,753 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2020-11-02 01:42:49,754 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2020-11-02 01:42:49,754 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT blobs.hash AS blobs_hash 
FROM blobs 
WHERE blobs.hash = ?
2020-11-02 01:42:49,754 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('qz78diGV8TjV31akJUBfHZUopUX5iC7rnHIUhQ==',)
2020-11-02 01:42:49,754 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```